# Apache Graceful restart requested every 5 seconds

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, process

I have a Debian 9.13 server, updated. In the Apache error log I have this message every 5 seconds:

```
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:07.000842 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7091] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:09.913896 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:10.084091 2021] [:notice] [pid 7091] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:10.088484 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:10.088502 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7091] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:10.877117 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:11.050083 2021] [:notice] [pid 7091] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:11.055795 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:11.055816 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7091] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:13.310891 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:13.461359 2021] [:notice] [pid 7091] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:13.465992 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:13.466015 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7091] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:16.660820 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:16.854361 2021] [:notice] [pid 7091] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:16.859235 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:16.859256 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7091] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:17.819697 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:18.001002 2021] [:notice] [pid 7091] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:18.009108 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7091] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2u configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 19 23:15:18.009130 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7091] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

It gives me a lot of problems and server crashes. Any clue as to what I need to modify?

Comment: This type of behaviour usually looks to happen due to misconfigured cronjobs. Looking at similar logs on the internet, they range from log rotation to cerbots, but they are all due to cronjobs requesting an action that leads to apache restarting. So it seems wise to check your crons.

Comment: Sure enough, I have identified the job causing the restart.  Was the following:
`
v-update-sys-queue letsencrypt 
`
Thank you very much for solving the problem.